# Probablity of one being vowel and other consonant when two letters are randomly chosen from the word "EDUCATION"

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

My solution to this question would be:

Total favourable cases= C(5,1)*C(4,1)

Total possible cases= C(9,2)

Which yields the answer: 5/9      [ Which is correct according to the textbook answer ]

**But my curiosity is, for what problem would I be solving to if I did the following:**

{C(5,1)/C(9,1)} * {C(4,1)/C(8,1)}

*I multiplied the probability of getting a vowel and that of a getting consonant. I know it is incorrect but it kind of seems right to me and I can't logically disapprove it*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect because you now fixed the order: You picked a two-letter "word" instead of a group of two letters. That way you get half the probability in this case.

Comment: So I would be calculating the combinations in a condition where first letter must be a vowel and the next a consonant and vice versa? Sorry, I couldn't still comprehend it . Thanks for your answer though .

Comment: I think I got it. So, if I add two of those operations, I would get my answer because, at first, I did it in a particular order and the 2nd time I reversed the order and added the both. :)

Comment: @BikashAdhikari that's right: you did vowel followed by consonant. For ordered choices we use a multiplication rule (if the choices are independent).